# Laravel controller can't get cookie

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm pretty new to laravel 5.6 and I want to use cookie inside a controller but I'm not able to retrieve cookie.

My purpose is to save some data inside cookie rather than get them on url because I don't want something like :

> www.test.com/case/10156/folder/562/client/896/

but something more like

> www.test.com/case/folder/client

So my function when I clikc on a link :

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(e){
    $.cookie("affaire", $(this).data("affaire"));
    $(location).attr('href',$(this).data("href"));
});
```

It works well, on chrome I can see the cookie "affaire".
I'm redirect to /lots so my route is:

```
    Route::get('/lots', ['as' => 'lots', 'uses' => 'Copro\LotController@index']);
```

And my LotController@index :

```
    public function index()
    {
        $case_id = Cookie::get('affaire');
        dd($case_id);
    }
```

But it return "null" (I add "use Cookie" at the beginning of my controller) so I can't use this value to do something else.

I tried with Request :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $copro_id = $request->cookie('affaire');
    dd($copro_id);
}
```

But it doesn't work either.

Someone know how to retrieve cookie ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I finally found a solution to my problem :

https://pineco.de/accessing-front-end-cookies-laravel/

Cookies are encrypt with laravel so we must enter cookie name inside except list of the middleware.